# Receiving connection timeout error when call PQconnectdbParams to connect to Postgres

Tags: postgresql

What are the allowed format for sending "connection string" to the `PQconnectdbParams` method to connect to Postgres DB?

I am trying the following, but it's not working and receiving timeout errors always. I am not sure what I was doing is wrong.

```
provider_dsn := 'host=xxx.xxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com port=5432 dbname=dbname password=my_password user=user_name'
```

Error message receiving is as follows

```
ERROR:  could not connect to the postgresql server: timeout expired
```

I can provide further details if required.

**Note**: I can connect the DB using `psql` command from the terminal but can't when I use `PQconnectdbParams` with same credentials.

Comment: `PQconnectdbParams()` doesn't take a connection string. The parameters it does accept are listed at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS

Comment: @DanielVérité Thanks a lot, I have verified the format and it's correct. Still same error, not sure what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up the different connection functions.

Your call would be correct with `PQconn`. `PQconnectdbParams` takes two parameters per connection string keyword

Replace `PQconnectdbParams` with `PQconn` and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for response. Seems there is no issue in connection string. I think problem may be in some where else. I am still working on this. Will post here once I found. I just posted to make sure whether I have any problem with connection string, just confirmed there is no issue in connection string.

Comment: Just replace `PQconnectdbParams` with `PQconn` in your code and leave everything else as it is. Why is that such a problem?

Comment: I am facing this issue while using pglogical extension. Not in my own logics.

Comment: But that's a different problem than what you wrote in your question. Maybe start another question where you explain the situation with sufficient detail.